# How to perform a nasty insert/update with lots of data, possible key violations and error list return

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I am looking for a strategy for this complicated operation to perform.**
We used to have a solution using NHibernate, it was ok for little amounts of data, but now its just way too slow.

The client uploads a file with card ID's into the system, file could contain up to ~150+k card ID's, which are assigned to a customer group.

A single record is either inserted, either his state changes.
Table eg.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
|card_id* | card_group_id* |state |   
|  11112  |       meow     |  0   |
|  11131  |       meow     |  1   |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Some ID's may violate PK/one of three FKs, and those ID's should be returned to the client.

So I basicly need to perform a somewhat one-at-a-time insert, "*did it work? OK. if not, add to failed ID list.*"

**Can you suggest me a strategy on achieving this?**

I **can't tolerate data loss** like 1 bad ID failing the operation for another 1000 in the same statement, it needs to be **somewhat fast** so the client doesn't starve to death waiting for a result notification.

The backend is ASP.NET-based, with database in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Add your data to a staging table with no constraints with a Bulkinsert, and Merge to your final table. Return the ones that were not inserted to the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool for the job. In this case is SSIS, and probably [Merge Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141703.aspx). From two sources (one the table, the other the file) create a merge, then take the two outputs, insert the not-matched and insert into errors the matched. SSIS will give you batching, bulk insert, input file parsing and so much more.

Do not attempt to do this in straight SQL, handling 150k input records is far from trivial and you'll end up writing a single-use app instead of using an off-the-shelf component.

Answer (score 1):

[BULKINSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365(v=sql.120).aspx) your Data to a [@TEMPTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx), then iterate over it with a [CURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms180169(v=sql.120).aspx).

Problems:

- Quick & Dirty
- Cursor PERFORMANCE!!